# Get last modified date of the view

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I am building a view, to which i need to attach a column which would be the last modified date for the query/view.
I have tried to hardcode the value in the view itself but that is not acceptable as we need to attach a system generated date for this

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me. What if 10 concurrent sessions run a query using the view? Which value should that column show? Also: Postgres 9.3 is not long maintained or supported, you should plan an upgrade to a supported version as soon as possible.

Comment: This is for Audit purposes and we need to know when the query was changed.
We are looking for last modified date of the query and not the last executed date of the view

Comment: Well, you wrote "Executed date". But anyways. Postgres does not store the time when an object is modified through DDL. The only way you could achieve this, is with an even trigger that is stores the current time when a DDL statement is executed